# Python: Is it possible to do a "deep class override"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, subclass

I want to create a subclass of `dict` that includes a custom comparison function that applies to all nested dicts.  This example class ignores all dict values with the key 'j' at the top level, but doesn't replace lower level dicts when a copy is made:

```
import copy
p = {'a': 1, 'j': 2, 'c': [{'j':'cat','k':'dog'}]}

class udict(dict):
    def __init__(self, x):
        dict.__init__(self, copy.deepcopy(x))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return all([self[k]==other[k] for k in set(self.keys())-set('j')])

a = udict(p)
b = udict(p)
a==b             # True
b['j'] = 5
a==b             # True - 'j' keys are imaginary and invisible
b['a'] = 5
a==b             # False
b = udict(p)
b['c'][0]['j'] = 'bird'
a==b             # False (should be True, but list contains dicts, not udicts)
```

I could manually tree-walk arbitrarily deep data structures replacing each dict with a udict, but if I have to walk the data structure anyway, I'll just do the comparison in the recursion without defining a custom class.

So is there a way to define a custom subclass that automatically replaces all embedded instances of the base class?

Comment: You have a bug: `udict() == udict(x=0)` gives True.

Comment: The example is supposed to be minimal and clearly illustrative, not bulletproof.  The real code will address corner cases, including the fact that dict() accepts more than one arg.

Comment: yep - just be aware that this bug might really byte you - "all" returns "True" for an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler approach requires no copying of data, and the recursion that replaces selected dicts with a subclass is short, explicit, and easily understandable.  The subclass overrides only the equality test, it doesn't need `__init__` or `__copy__` methods:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return <custom equality test result>

def replaceable(var):
    if <dict instance should be replaced by subclass instance>:
        return <dict of instances to be replaced>
    return {}

def replacedict(var)
    if isinstance(var, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(var):
            var[i] = replacedict(v)
    elif isinstance(var, dict):
        for k, v in var.items():
            var[k] = replacedict(v)
        rep = replaceable(var)
        for k, v in rep.items():
            rep[k] = MyDict(v)
    return(var)
```

For the specific case of testing JSON Schemas to test if multiple properties can be merged into a patternProperties:

```
def replaceable(var):
    if 'type' in var and var['type'] == 'object' and \
        'properties' in var and isinstance(var['properties'],dict):
        return var['properties']
    return {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the `__deepcopy__` method on your 
custom class: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html -
You will have to "use recursion" - but it still seens it will be easier than anythng else you'd have to do in there:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def custom_deepcopier(dct, memo=None):
    result = MD()
    for key, value in dct.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = MD(value)
        else:
            result[key] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    return result

class MD(dict):
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        if x:
            dict.__init__(self, custom_deepcopier(x))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        ...
    __deepcopy__ = custom_deepcopier
```

In declaring things this way, the `custom_deepcopier` is used both as the `deepcopy` method called authomatically when deep-copying one of your custom dicts, but can also be "bootstraped"  with a plain dictionary, being called as a stand-alone function.

And finally, not directly related to the answer you need, on your real code, consider inheriting from `collections.UserDict` instead of dict - there are some shortcuts in the native code for dicts that might bring in bad surprises for you in your inherited classes. (including in the inherent recursion used for `__eq__`)